# Rx (RxKotlin) - rightGroupJoin using groupJoin - merge / combine two observables of different types

Tags: rxjs, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-kotlin, rx-kotlin2

After struggling for a few days now, on what seems to be a simple task, I come to you guys:)

Idea is simple. I have two streams/observables, 'left' and 'right'.
I want items from 'right' to buffer/collect/aggregate to 'current' item in 'left'.
Thus, each item in 'left' defines a new 'window', while all 'right' items will bind to that window, until a new 'left' item is emitted. So, to visualize:

**Task:**
'left'     : |- A - - - - - B - - C - - - -|
'right'   :       |- 1 - 2 - 3 -4 - 5 - 6 - - -|
'result' : |- - - - - - - -x - - -y - - - -z|   ( `Pair<Left, List<Right>>`)
*Where: **A,1** ; **B,4** (so x) ; **C** (so y) are emitted on the same time*
*So:       x = Pair(A, [1,2,3]),   y = Pair(B, [4, 5])*
*And:    'right' & 'result' complete/terminate when 'left' does*
*So:      z = Pair(C, [6]) - emitted as a result of 'left' completing*

**----**
**EDIT 2 - FINAL SOLUTION!**
In order to aggregate 'right' items with the next 'left' and not the previous one, I changed the code to this much shorter/simpler one:

```
fun <L, R> Observable<L>.rightGroupJoin(right: Observable<R>): Observable<Pair<L, List<R>>> {
    return this.share().run {
        zipWith(right.buffer(this), BiFunction { left, rightList ->
            Pair(left, rightList)
        })
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1 - initial solution!**
Taken from @Mark's (accepted) answer below, here's what I came up with.
It is separated into smaller methods because I also do `multiRightGroupJoin()` to join in as many (right) streams as I want.

```
fun <T, R> Observable<T>.rightGroupJoin(right: Observable<R>): Observable<Pair<T, List<R>>> {
    return this.share().let { thisObservable ->    //use 'share' to avoid multi-subscription complications, e.g. multi calls to **preceding** doOnComplete
        thisObservable.flatMapSingle { t ->        //treat each 'left' as a Single
            bufferRightOnSingleLeft(thisObservable, t, right)
        }
    }
}
```

Where:

```
private fun <T, R> bufferRightOnSingleLeft(left: Observable<*>, leftSingleItem: T, right: Observable<R>)
    : Single<Pair<T, MutableList<R>>> {

    return right.buffer(left)                              //buffer 'right' until 'left' onNext() (for each 'left' Single) 
        .map { Pair(leftSingleItem, it) }
        .first(Pair(leftSingleItem, emptyList()))   //should be only 1 (list). THINK firstOrError
}
```

**----**

**What I got so far**
After much reading and the understanding that somehow there's no implementation for this out of the box, I've decided to use `groupJoin`, mostly using [this link](https://leecampbell.com/2011/03/14/rx-part-9-join-window-buffer-and-group-join/), like so: *(many problems and places to improve here, don't use this code)*

```
private fun <T, R> Observable<T>.rightGroupJoin(right: Observable<R>): Observable<Pair<T, List<R>>> {

var thisCompleted = false //THINK is it possible to make the groupJoin complete on the left(this)'s onComplete automatically?
val thisObservable = this.doOnComplete { thisCompleted = true }
        .share() //avoid weird side-effects of multiple onSubscribe calls

//join/attach 'right/other' stream to windows (buffers), starting and ending on each 'this/left' onNext
return thisObservable.groupJoin(

    //bind 'right/other' stream to 'this/left'
    right.takeUntil { thisCompleted }//have an onComplete rule THINK add share() at the end?

    //define when windows start/end ('this/left' onNext opens new window and closes prev)
    , Function<T, ObservableSource<T>> { thisObservable }

    //define 'right/other' stream to have no windows/intervals/aggregations by itself
    // -> immediately bind each emitted item to a 'current' window(T) above
    , Function<R, ObservableSource<R>> { Observable.empty() }

    //collect the whole 'right' stream in 'current' ('left') window
    , BiFunction<T, Observable<R>, Single<Pair<T, List<R>>>> { t, rObs ->
        rObs.collect({ mutableListOf<R>() }) { acc, value ->
            acc.add(value)
        }.map { Pair(t, it.toList()) }

    }).mergeAllSingles()
}
```

I also used similar usage to create a `timedBuffer()` - same as `buffer(timeout)` but with a timestamp on each buffer(`List`) to know when it started. Basically by running the same code on an `Observable.interval(timeout)` (as the 'left')

**Problems / Questions (from the easiest to the hardest)**

1. Is it the best way of doing something like that? Isn't it an overkill?
2. Is there a better way (must be) for completing the 'result' (and 'right') when 'left' is completed? Without this ugly boolean logic?
3. This usage seem to mess up the order of the rx. See code and print below:

   ```
   leftObservable
   .doOnComplete {
       log("doOnComplete - before join")
    }
   .doOnComplete {
       log("doOnComplete 2 - before join")
    }
   .rightGroupJoin(rightObservable)
   .doOnComplete {
       log("doOnComplete - after join")
    }
   ```

Prints (sometimes! Looks like a race condition) the following:
`doOnComplete - before join`
`doOnComplete - after join`
`doOnComplete 2 - before join`

4. On first run of the above code, `doOnComplete - after join` is not called, on the second time it's called **twice**. Third time is like the first, forth is like the second, etc...
   Both 3,4 are ran using this code. Probably has something to do with the subscribe {} usage? Note that I don't hold the disposable.
   This stream finishes because I GC the 'left' observable

   ```
   leftObservable.subscribeOn().observeOn()
   .doOnComplete{log...}
   .rightGroupJoin()
   .doOnComplete{log...}
   .subscribe {}
   ```

Note1: adding `.takeUntil { thisCompleted }` after `mergeAllSingles()` seems to fix #4.

Note2: After using this method to join multiple streams and applying 'Note1', it's apparent that the onComplete (before the groupJoin() call !!!) will be called as many times as there are 'right' Observables, probably meaning that the cause is the `right.takeUntil { thisCompleted }`, is it really important to close the 'right' stream?

Note3: concerning Note1, it seems very much related to takeUntil vs. takeWhile. Using takeWhile lowers the doOnComplete calls, and it's somehow logical. Still trying to figure it out better.

5. Can you think of a multiGroupJoin, or in our case, multiRightGroupJoin, other than running zip on groupJoin * rightObservablesCount?

Please ask anything you like. I know for a fact the my usage of the subscribe/disposable and the manual onComplete are not the way, I'm just not sure enough what is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something as simple as this should work :

```
@JvmStatic
fun main(string: Array<String>) {
    val left = PublishSubject.create<String>()
    val right = PublishSubject.create<Int>()

    left.flatMapSingle { s ->  right.buffer(left).map { Pair(s, it) }.firstOrError() }
            .subscribe{ println("Group : Letter : ${it.first}, Elements : ${it.second}") }


    left.onNext("A")
    right.onNext(1)
    right.onNext(2)
    right.onNext(3)
    left.onNext("B")
    right.onNext(4)
    right.onNext(5)
    left.onNext("C")
    right.onNext(6)
    left.onComplete()
}
```

Output :

```
Group : Letter : A, Elements : [1, 2, 3]
Group : Letter : B, Elements : [4, 5]
Group : Letter : C, Elements : [6]
```

Your `Observable` of interest is the left, so subscribe to it. Then just buffer the right by the left observable's next emission or completion.  You're only ever interested in a single result of each upstream left emission, so just use `flatMapSingle`.  I chose `firstOrError()` but obviously could have a default item or other error handling or even a `flatMapMaybe` coupled with `firstElement()`

**Edit**

OP has had further Q&A and discovered that the original question and above solution to buffer right values with the previous left emission, until the next left emission (as above), is not the required behaviour.  New required behaviour is to buffer right values to the NEXT left emission as so:

```
@JvmStatic
    fun main(string: Array<String>) {
        val left = PublishSubject.create<String>()
        val right = PublishSubject.create<Int>()


        left.zipWith (right.buffer(left), 
                BiFunction<String, List<Int>, Pair<String, List<Int>>> { t1, t2 -> Pair(t1, t2)
        }).subscribe { println("Group : Letter : ${it.first}, Elements : ${it.second}") }

        left.onNext("A")
        right.onNext(1)
        right.onNext(2)
        right.onNext(3)
        left.onNext("B")
        right.onNext(4)
        right.onNext(5)
        left.onNext("C")
        right.onNext(6)
        left.onComplete()
    }
```

Which produces a different final result as left values are zipped with previous right values, until next left emission (inverse).

Output :

```
Group : Letter : A, Elements : []
Group : Letter : B, Elements : [1, 2, 3]
Group : Letter : C, Elements : [4, 5]
```

Comment: Looks easy and perfect. Will implement soon to see if it fits, thx!

Comment: Does it make sense to do `val left = PublishSubject.create<String>().publish().refCount` ? Otherwise any preceding doOnComplete is called twice (we pass 'left' two times in your code)

Comment: The subject I used was just for pushing events, you could easily have an emitter, or custom observable. If it makes sense to use a `ConnectableObservable` that only emits when subscribed, over a "hot" observable then that's fine, as it's a matter of implementation details IMO. `doOn` operators should only really be used for side effects, or logging, which is how I assume you're using them.

Comment: Yeah I use them to log, for sanity checks. It just feels an anti pattern to rx to have them called multiple times, but I don't really know (hence the question). Thank you!

Comment: After further QA, it's apparent that this solution aggregates 'right' on a 'left' single that **was already emitted**, meaning that 'right' items are paired with the previous 'left', instead of the next one.
The solution is to change `flatMapSingle` to `zipWith(right.buffer(left), ..)`, so that when a 'left' is emitted, the already-emitted 'right' items are paired with it.  Can you please edit your answer to add this solution? I still want it to be the accepted one. Also edited my question (with the new solution)

Answer (score 0):

At first sight i'd use 2 `scan`s here. Example:

```
data class Result(val left: Left?, val rightList: List<Right>) {
    companion object {
        val defaultInstance: Result = Result(null, listOf())
    }
}

leftObservable.switchMap { left -> 
    rightObservable.scan(listOf()) {list, newRight -> list.plus(newRight)}
        .map { rightsList -> Result(left, rightList) }
}
.scan(Pair(Result.defaultInstance, Result.defaultInstance)) { oldPair, newResult -> 
    Pair(oldPair.second, newResult)
}
.filter { it.first != it.second }
.map { it.first }
```

The only problem here is to handle `onComplete`, not sure how to do it

Comment: Thx! Will try that out soon:)